# How can I change the language of the months provided by LocalDate?

Tags: java, translation, localdate

I need to find the current month and print it. I have the following code:

```
this.currentDate=LocalDate.now();
this.month = this.currentDate.getMonth();
```

The problem is that the month is in English and I need to print it in French, to match the rest of the website language. How can I select the language of the month provided by the `LocalDate.now()` method without needing to do a manual translation each time I need to display it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can convert the `Month` type into a `String` using `getDisplayName()`, which can change the locale to French as follows:

```
this.currentDate = LocalDate.now();
this.month = this.currentDate.getMonth().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.FRANCE);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `DateTimeFormatter` to create a formatter for French as follows:

```
final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, dd MMMM, yyyy", Locale.FRENCH);
final String month = LocalDate.now().format(formatter);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was not the ENUM country option then I used default and its solved:

```
LocalDate.now().getMonth().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.getDefault())
```

Comment: Just read *The Java Tutorials* section [*Creating a Locale*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/create.html). Free of cost, by Oracle.