# Translation of LocalDateTime with DateTimeFormatter in modularized program (JDK17)

Tags: java, translation, localdate, modularization

I try to translate a LocalDateTime to the current used language like shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51843932

Running the program in Eclipse works as intended, but when it gets deployed with maven and jlink it falls back to english.

I assume I am missing a module to be required? Its a JDK17 modularized application.

I tried:

```
Locale loc = new Locale("de", "DE");
Locale.setDefault(loc);
lblDateTime.setText(LocalDateTime.now()
    .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, dd. MMMM yyyy - HH:mm:ss");
```

```
lblDateTime.setText(LocalDateTime.now()
    .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, dd. MMMM yyyy - HH:mm:ss", Locale.GERMAN);
```

```
lblDateTime.setText(LocalDateTime.now()
    .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, dd. MMMM yyyy - HH:mm:ss").localizedBy(Locale.GERMAN);
```

Result in Eclipse in all 3 cases:
[image: Eclipse result]

Result after deployment:
[image: deploy result]

The module info:

```
module [name] {
    [...]

    requires transitive javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires transitive javafx.graphics;
    requires org.apache.logging.log4j.core;
    requires javafx.base;
    requires org.controlsfx.controls;
    requires java.base;
    requires java.desktop;
}
```

Update 1: 
The result of `System.getProperty("java.locale.providers")` in both cases is `null`.

Update 2: 
Adding `requires jdk.localedata;` to the `module-info.java` solved the issue. See accepted answer.

Comment: That’s weird. It would seem that your installation is missing locale data or is trying to pick them up from a wrong source. In particular I wonder that you specify the full form of the day of week ( `EEEE`), but on the installation the abbreviated form is printed ( `Wed`, not even `Wednesday`).

Comment: To investigate where Java is trying to get its locale data from you may print out `System.getProperty("java.locale.providers")` and tell us the result from both your own Eclipse and from the deployed program (you may get null or an empty string).

Comment: @user16320675 - Thanks for pointing it out. I corrected it.

Comment: @OleV.V. I updated the Question with the results.

Comment: Thanks. `null` should imply that the default should be used, which in Java 17 is `CLDR,COMPAT`. If the CLDR (Unicode Common Locale Data Repository) data would be missing from or incomplete in your installation, I find that weird and a bit hard to believe. Does the same happen for other locales?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you build an optimized environment but want support for localization, you must include [`jdk.localedata`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/jdk.localedata/module-summary.html) in your environment.

> Provides the locale data for locales other than [US locale](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html#US).

So either, specify `--add-modules jdk.localedata` to `jlink` when creating the runtime image or add `requires jdk.localedata;` to your `module-info.java`.